# Is a surface curve made of planar points necessarily a line?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces, curves, submanifold

I am having trouble proving the following statement, which at first seemed intuitively true to me.

Let $S$ be a surface in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. Suppose that there is a curve $\gamma$ in $S$ whose all points are planar, i.e., the second fundamental form $\alpha$ (or, equivalently, the shape operator) of $S$ vanishes at all points of $\gamma$. Does this imply that $\gamma$ is part of a straight line?

This question is related to the existence of non-straight asymptotic curves in $S$. It is well-known that a curve $\gamma$ such that $\alpha(\dot{\gamma},\dot{\gamma})=0$ need not be part of a straight line.

EDIT: As pointed out by Arctic Char, the claim is not true in general. What happens if we assume that, for every open neighborhood $U$ (in $S$) of the curve $\gamma$, there is no plane $P$ such that $U \subset P$?

Comment: When $S$ is a plane in $\mathbb R^3$, any curve $\gamma$ in $S$ is planar.

Comment: Your last question "...has a planar curve $\gamma$ (as defined above) that is not contained in a plane?" seems very odd. Do you mean to ask whether this curve $\gamma$ has to be a straight line?

Comment: @Ernie060 That's my edit, now I have changed it to the original one by the OP. I guess I might have misinterpret their new question.

Comment: But I still want to clarify, at the end when you say a plane, do you mean that $S$ is not a plane? If that's the case, one of the deleted answer answers your question.

Comment: @Arctic Char Thanks for clearing things up. In the meantime, I also deleted my answer, since it doesn't answer OP's question well (I think...)

Comment: "What happens if we assume that the curve does not lie on a plane?" Then it cannot be a line, for every line in $\Bbb R^3$ lies on some plane. Thus I'm sure that this cannot be the thing you meant to ask --- can you perhaps spend a little time reformulating your question very clearly and carefully, so that we can answer it without it morphing out from underneath?

Comment: Perhaps the formulation you were seeking for "does not lie in a plane" was "for every open neighborhood $U$ (in $S$) of the curve $\gamma$, there is no plane $P$ such that $U \subset P$."

Comment: @JohnHughes Yes, that is exactly what I wanted. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It seems to me that @Ernie060's deleted answer is correct. The surface is tangent to the $xy$-plane along that parabola and those are all planar points of the surface, but these are the only planar points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take for example the surface parametrised by
$$
  x(u,v) = (u, v, (u^2-v)^3).
$$
It easy to see that the second derivatives $x_{uu}$, $x_{uv}$, $x_{vv}$ are zero along the curve $v = u^2$, and hence the shape operator vanishes along this curve. However the curve is a parabola in the $xy$-plane, not a straight line.

Comment: But it still lies in a plane.

Comment: Yes... but the OP asks 'does this imply that $\gamma$ is part of a straight line?", right?

Comment: And the lastly added question "do we have a surface $S$ in $R^3$ which has a planar curve $γ$ (as defined above) that is not contained in a plane?" seems formulated a bit strange. I guessed the OP meant to ask: "Given a curve on a surface _which is not a plane_ along which the 2nd fundamental form vanishes, does this imply that the curve is a straight line?" Let me ask the OP for clarification ... :)